# How can I stop hv_utils from logging a message in kern.log + syslog 2000+ times a second? Kern.log 32G in size and syslog is 11G

Tags: log, logging, syslog, logs

I recently received a warning message from my Ubuntu 16.04.2 VM on Hyper-V that 99% of my disk is full. Upon further inspection I noticed that my /var/ directory was using over 108G of space and that the 108G could attributed to only four files:

- 32G     /var/log/kern.log
- 41G     /var/log/kern.log.1  (deleted)
- 11G     /var/log/syslog
- 22G     /var/log/syslog.1 (deleted)

I did some polling and noticed that the below line was being logged over 2000 times a second in kern.log (I didn't poll syslog but the same message is logged there)

- Mar 27 22:08:28 VM-Ubuntu kernel: [ 2830.661832] hv_utils: Using TimeSync version 4.0

How can I stop hv_utils from hogging all the memory on my vm?? Any help would be appreciated...

Cheers,
-Sam

Comment: I just ran into the same problem and ran across this thread after a google search. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The fix is relatively easy.
Edit settings of the desired virtual machine. Go to Integration Services and disable "Time Synchronization"

Comment: Thank you this has seemed to stop the nonsensical logging!!